# Azure Functions ScriptHost initialization failed error

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm attempting to write a simple Azure Function app and I want to reference some other existing projects in my VS 2017 solution.  These other projects have a reference to some custom logging code which in turn references the Nuget packages Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.

When I start my functions app in VS2017, I get the following error:

```
[3/21/2018 5:42:12 PM] ScriptHost initialization failed
[3/21/2018 5:42:12 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

It doesn't matter whether I directly reference the above three Nuget packages in my Functions project or not.  I'm using the 1.0.9 version of Azure Functions.

I've posted a highly simplified example of a project showing this error in a GitHub repo here: https://github.com/chriswill/FunctionDemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting. Issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/181)